# return object in js

Tags: javascript, object, return

I declare an array globally:

```
var array = new Array;
```

I declare constructor for Element

```
function Element(type, format ) {
this.type= type;
this.format = format;
this.returnElement = function() { return this.element; }
}
```

I want to return the value of one of parameters while it's in the array:

```
function analyse()
{
     for(var i=0, len=array.length; i < len; i++)
     {   
        var a = array[i];
            var b = a.type;
            alert(b);
     }  
 }
```

}

Now, I want to return the value of the object's property at i.

Comment: Mind posting what error do you get? And where is `var array` being defined? Using `var` in front of it makes it a local variable if inside a function.

Comment: Couple of things: to declare a new array you should just use `array = ()`. Second `this.element` doesn't exist in your object. Third, you never use your function in the loop. Fourth you're always grabbing the first element of the array in your loop. Fifth, your array has no members. Sixth, unless your your array members contain a parameter called `type` that last line will do nothing. Seventh, your loop does nothing other than assign some variables; it provides no information at all.

Comment: What is your question?  It doesn't work does not describe what you're trying to do.  You are iterating through your array and what do you want to do during that iteration?  What are you looking for?  What do you want to return when you find it?

Comment: @tkone: first, use [] not (). Second, this.element may be a prototype property. Fourth, he doesn't grab any single element. Sixth: you call these "properties" or "keys", not "parameters"

Comment: Oops. Wrong syntax. Long day. It may be but he is not showing it,  so we have no clue. You call them properties. I call them parameters. My bike shed is red. Yours is blue.

Comment: I have an array of objects. I added elements to the array earlier, just didn't show it here. Now, I want to return the value of the object's property at i. How can i do it?

Comment: ok, resolved, it was trivial and i'm dumb. just added these lines of code: var element = new Element(); element = array[i]; and it worked

Answer (score 0):

No idea what you exactly want, but there are several mistakes:

- `Element` is no object, but a constructor function (which is of course a Function object, yes)
- `array.slice(0)` empties the `array` and returns a new array with all the elements from index 0 up
- `var a =` becomes that new array, and is not an Element object. An array has no property "type"

You might want to do

```
 for (var i=0, len=array.length; i < len; i++) {   
        var a = array[0];
        //console.assert(a instanceof Element, "wrong array component detected");
        var b = a.type;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

ok, resolved, it was trivial and i'm dumb. just added these lines of code:

```
var element = new Element(); 
element = array[i];
```

and it worked...